# Tsung - Using Erlang expressions in variable substitution

Tags: erlang, tsung

In Tsung you can substitute variables like this: `%%_counter%%`. But how do I do something like `%%_counter * 2 + 1%%`?

Comment: Kindly, check below thread if you can help, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43798227/6419028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of adding `%%_tsung_userid%%` and `%%_counter%%` into the variable `%%_total%%`.

```
<setdynvars sourcetype="eval" code="fun({Pid,DynVars})->
                   {ok,Tsung_userid} = ts_dynvars:lookup(tsung_userid,DynVars),
                   {ok,Counter} = ts_dynvars:lookup(counter,DynVars),
                   Tsung_userid + Counter end.">
        <var name="total" />
</setdynvars>
```

I don't know if there's a more concise way.